# Simple tool (gem) to convert directories of markdown files to GitHub style wiki

Tags: markdown, wiki, ruby, github

I have a directory containing many markdown files as well as other directories containing markdown files. I have everything in version control and don't really want to re-organize everything, but I would like to be able to convert the contents of the directory to an html wiki. (I like the style of GitHub's wiki pages). Is there a **simple** tool out there that can do this? I would prefer something written in Ruby.

I found these two gems:

- https://github.com/github/markup
- https://github.com/gollum/gollum

This issue is github/markup can only convert markdown to html. It can't automatically generate a complete wiki. Gollum seems like what I want. But does a lot more than I want. **Is there something simpler than Gollum?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a full wiki you should take a look at [gitit](http://gitit.net/) it can generate a wiki from a set of markdown pages, including having a directory structure, is git aware and can produce a set of wiki pages from markdown, (and a lot of other stuff), by using pandoc for the input processing.

- It looks a lot easier to use than gollum.

If you just would like to make a set of static pages from your markdown you should take a look at [Jekyll](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll) as used by [github pages](https://pages.github.com/) - with the addition of a few extra files your markdown should be simple to change into a static web site.

- Jekyll is written in Ruby
- Use html or markdown as input
- Templating available
- and plugins
- getting started is simple.